# Data structure for sequence

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm training for the test from data structures and I can't solve this problem:

> Design a data structure which keeps sequence a_1, ..., a_n 
>       and can perform two operations on it:
>
> 1. set a_i to value x
> 2. count how many times value x occurs in a sequence between two indexes: 
>         i, and j; just to be sure I made it clear (I'm not good at English) it means 
>         to return `|{a_k: a_k = x and i <= k <= j}|` for a given: x, i, j.
>
> constraints:
>
> - a_i are from interval [0, ..., 10^9],
> - n is smaller - it is less than 10^5

both operations should work in at most O(log n) time. The only way I see it is, unfortunately, O(log^2 n). We keep interval tree with `maps<int,int>` in nodes, which count how many times x occurs in a subtree. It is also important not to keep in maps values that occur 0 times (memory complexity).

How can I solve it better? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6):

This is a BST with two data fields:

```
BSTNode<E>{
   int index;
   E value;
   BSTNode left, right;
}
```

Order your tree by the indices so that searching is O(lg n): which helps with inserting and setting (`seta_i to value x`).

To `count how many times value x occurs in a sequence between two indexes: i, j`

- Find the immediate common parent of i and j: http://www.geekviewpoint.com/java/bst/immediate_common_parent
- Then traverse the subtree rooted at the common parent: for each visit, count only the nodes whose value is `x`. This is similar to summing single children http://www.geekviewpoint.com/java/bst/sum_single_children or visiting leaves in order (from the same site).

EDIT:

after finding the common parent of `i` and `j`, instead of traversing the subtree, it is possible to simply look up the frequency of a value: Each node (here the commonParent) can have a frequency map: `Map<E,Integer> childrenFreq = new HashMap<E,Integer>()`. This would be O(1) once the common parent is found in O(lg n)

Comment: When you traverse the entire subtree, that is at least `Ω(k)` where `k` is the number of occurrences. It should be `O(log n)`, but `k` need not be dominated by `log n`.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer : after finding the common parent of `i` and `j`, instead of traversing the subtree, it is possible to simply look up the frequency of a value: Each node (here the commonParent) can have a frequency map: `Map<E,Integer> childrenFreq = new HashMap<E,Integer>()`. This would be O(1) once the common parent is found in O(lg n)

Comment: Yes, and updating a `Hashmap` should be O(1), so setting the value of `a_i` would remain O(log n), I think. So edit that into your answer, I'd say.

Comment: Also mention why that leaves setting the value of `a_i` at O(log n), please. I'll upvote now anyway, but if I find out you didn't, I may retract it later ;)

Comment: @Daniel Fischer : Setting `a_i to value x` means finding the node with index `a_i` which is lg n and then replacing the value of that node to `x` which is O(1). I thought that was obvious. I will replace `searching is fast` with `searching is lg n`. Will that clarify?

Comment: Ah, but now you must also update the O(log n) frequency maps. As Hashmaps, that can be done in O(1) per map. That was what I wanted to have spelled out.